# WPF SelectedItem within a Datagrid Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I have the following code which works well, but I am wondering how I can get a SelectedItem when I select an item from the combobox. I have tried to do this in the line with the **** but this doesn't work, I believe it is close, any suggestions would be great. Thanks

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Name}">
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                Value="{Binding DataContext.AnotherCollection,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType=Window}}"/>
        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                Value="{Binding DataContext.AnotherCollection,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType=Window}}"/>
        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>

  *****<Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>****

    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

I do get this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'SelectedCustomer' property not found on 'object'
>   ''CustomerEligibility_D45A565716CF82DEEF89311760E7DDA725D9D002B7ED3873BE0158121BBE9D52'
>   (HashCode=20202357)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedCustomer;
>   DataItem='CustomerEligibility_D45A565716CF82DEEF89311760E7DDA725D9D002B7ED3873BE0158121BBE9D52'
>   (HashCode=20202357); target element is 'TextBlockComboBox' (Name='');
>   target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')

The Property in the ViewModel is

```
 private CustomerEligibility m_Name = null;

    public CustomerEligibility SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return m_Name; }
        set
        {
            m_Name = value;


            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is SelectedCustomer defined? You're probably getting a binding error message in your output window stating that SelectedCustomer isn't a property of you ComboBox

Comment: SelectedCustomer is a property of the type of collection that the combobox was bounded with e.g.  List<Customer>

Comment: But where is that property defined? You almost definitely do not have the right DataContext within the cell that the ComboBox is being created in and are getting a binding error from not being able to resolve the property.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying, it is defined in the ViewModel. The property is "public Customer SelectedCustomer ...." and I bind a "list<Customer>" to the DataContext, this has worked in other areas so not sure what I am missing here

Comment: Your right, in the output box I get this error

 BindingExpression path error: 'AnotherCollection' property not found on 'object' '  target element is 'TextBlockComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')